# Usando replace num caractere no meio de uma String para adicionar texto antes e depois da String

Tags: java, string, regex, replace

Tenho esta expressão armazenada numa `String`:

```
1 * Math.pow(x, 3.0) + 4 * Math.pow(x, 2.0) + 1 * Math.pow(x, 1.0) + 27
```

Porém, uso uma biblioteca de derivação que somente aceita o caractere `^` para fazer potenciação, então faço uma conversão nessa `String`, ficando assim:

```
1*x^3.0+4*x^2.0+1*x^1.0+27
```

A função de derivação me retorna uma `String` derivada no mesmo padrão da `String` convertida (`1.0+3.0*x^2.0+8.0*x`), e eu preciso calcular a expressão derivada com a função `eval()`, que somente aceita o `Math.pow()` como função de potenciação. Tentei usar:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[x\\^]", "Math.pow\\(\\x\\,");
str = str.replaceAll("[(?:\\,(?=0-9))]", "1");
```

E a primeira linha já ajuda bastante, porém não sei muito bem como eu adicionaria o expoente com parêntese depois da vírgula ou como saber o expoente.

EDIT: criei o seguinte código:

```
static String reConvertString(String str) {
    Pattern patterne = Pattern.compile("[^\\^]*\\^");
    Matcher matchere = patterne.matcher(str);
    int count = 0;
    while (matchere.find()) {
        count++;//conta a quantidade de ocorrencias do caractere ^
    }

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        int index = str.indexOf("^");
        str = str.replaceFirst("\\^", "z");//substituo por um caractere qualquer depois que acho a primeira ocorrencia
        System.out.println(index);
        str = str.replaceFirst("[xz]", "Math.pow\\(\\x\\, ");//o x^2.0 agora fica xz com o replace

        String teste=str.substring(index+1, index+2);//pega a potência
        str = str.replace(" ", teste+")");//fecha o parêntese da função
    }
    return str;
}
```

Porém meu output ficou assim:

> 10.0*Math.pow(Math.pow(x,4),t)z4.0-15.0*xz2.0

Não sei de onde surgiu o `t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `t` veio da palavra `Math` e o problema está nos índices que você passa para `substring` (os valores acabam coincidindo com o `t`).

De qualquer forma, para resolver isso com regex, estou assumindo algumas premissas:

- a base sempre é `x` (*mas no final coloco uma alternativa para bases que não sejam `x`*)
- o expoente sempre é um número (e não uma expressão mais complexa, por isso a solução abaixo não considera casos como `x ^ (a + b / c)`, por exemplo)

Para este caso mais simples, podemos usar algo como:

```
String str = "1*x^3.0+4*x^2.0+1*x^1.0+27";
str = str.replaceAll("x\\^(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)", "Math.pow(x, $1)");
System.out.println(str);
```

Estou assumindo que a base sempre é `x`, então eu coloco o próprio caractere `x` na expressão.

Depois eu uso `\\^`: o `^` possui significado especial em regex (significa ["o início da string"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)), então para que ele "perca seus poderes" preciso escapá-lo com `\` - mas dentro de uma `String` este caractere precisa ser escrito como `\\`, então o resultado final fica `\\^`. Assim, ele corresponde ao próprio caractere `^`.

Depois, para o expoente, eu uso `(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)`. Explicando de dentro para fora:

- `\\d`: [significa um dígito](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `+`: significa ["uma ou mais ocorrências"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Portanto, `\\d+` é "um ou mais dígitos"
- `\\.\\d+`: é um ponto seguido de um ou mais dígitos

Os parênteses mais externos formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim eu posso referenciá-lo posteriormente, usando `$1`.

Os parênteses internos usam a sintaxe `(?:`, que forma um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (assim eles não criam uma variável especial, como o `$1`). E o `?` que vem depois [torna este grupo opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Ou seja, o expoente pode ser tanto `1` quanto `1.0`. E este valor é capturado no grupo 1 (pois é o primeiro par de parênteses), podendo ser referenciado posteriormente com `$1` - que é o valor que uso na expressão de substituição.

Ou seja, a regex verifica se existe um `x` seguido de `^`, seguido de número e troca por `Math(x, $1)`, sendo que `$1` é o valor do número, que foi capturado pelo grupo de captura.

O resultado é:

> 1*Math.pow(x, 3.0)+4*Math.pow(x, 2.0)+1*Math.pow(x, 1.0)+27

---

A regex acima assume que não há espaços entre o `x`, o `^` e o expoente. Se quiser considerar espaços, pode usar `\\s*` (zero ou mais espaços):

```
str = str.replaceAll("x\\s*\\^\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)", "Math.pow(x, $1)");
```

---

Se a base pode ser algo diferente de `x`, pode trocar para `\w+` (um ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos), ou ainda para `[a-z]+` (uma ou mais letras de `a` a `z`):

```
String str = "1*x^3.0+4*y^2.0+1*z^1.0+27";
str = str.replaceAll("([a-z]+)\\s*\\^\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)", "Math.pow($1, $2)");
System.out.println(str);
```

Agora eu coloco as letras dentro de um grupo de captura, por isso a expressão passa a ter dois grupos: um para a base e outro para o expoente. Na expressão de substituição, eles são respectivamente `$1` e `$2`. O resultado é:

> 1*Math.pow(x, 3.0)+4*Math.pow(y, 2.0)+1*Math.pow(z, 1.0)+27

Se a variável pode ter letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas, basta trocar para `[a-zA-Z]+`.

---

Isso funciona para expressões mais simples. Mas se tiver coisas mais complexas (como `(x * 1 - 2) ^ (a - (1.24 / y))`), aí começa a ficar complexo demais usar regex, pois aí teria que analisar muitos fatores, como por exemplo se os parênteses estão balanceados (algo que é muito mais fácil de fazer sem regex). Neste caso, eu sugiro pesquisar por analisadores léxicos ou [*parsers* específicos](https://www.google.com/search?q=parse+arithmetic+expression+java).